# SBT proxy repository authentication

Tags: authentication, sbt

I'm trying to use an Artifactory server as proxy for the resolution of java/scala artifacts.

I'm referring to [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Proxy-Repositories.html) documentation, where the suggestion is to put the following lines in `~/.sbt/repositories`:

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/maven-releases/
```

Unfortunaely there's no mention on where I should put my authentication credentials, and

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

In the `buid.sbt` put the following:

```
credentials += Credentials("Artifactory Realm", "artifacts.schibsted.io", "username", "password")
```

The `Artifactory Realm` string is required as it is.